# Pandas df.to_CSV without quotation marks in output but keeping newline for multi-line content?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

So I have a df that has one column containing a text string that has to include `\n` and `,` to break up the text for readability and processing.

Sample:

`'Line A) This is some sample text\n\nLine B) This text, it goes into the column in question'`

My issue is that using df.to_CSV will wrap the content in "" when the file is created, which is unacceptable. So even though there are no quotes in the above example, this is what shows up in the cell in the CSV where it gets written:

`"Line A) This is some sample text`

`Line B) This text, it goes into the column in question"`

The mult-line string gets written into one cell, but gets wrapped in `" "`.

If I use the to_csv() parameters like `quoting=None` to get rid of the `" "` it works, but then the contents splits into two rows in the sheet instead of being in one cell.

Is there some way to use to_CSV() so that I can output a string that contains `\n` and `,` in a single cell without having it get wrapped in `" "`?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is it unacceptable? That's the standard for CSV formatting, and any CSV reader should be able to process it.

Comment: You also need quotes whenever the column contains `,`. Otherwise, how will you know that the comma isn't a delimiter?

Comment: Please provide code sample.

Comment: CSV files use the newline character to terminate a row unless quotes are used. Any conformant CSV reader will handle it okay. Can you expand on why this is unacceptable in your case?